# Populate array inside of function

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, function

I have a function that clears two arrays and then populates them with values received from a mysql server.

```
function sqlget() {
  var arrayA = [];
  var arrayB = [];
  con.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err,result,fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      arrayA.push(result[key].columnA);
      arrayB.push(result[key].columnB);
    });
  });
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is then call arrayA/arrayB outside of function and have it return the sql information fetched inside the function with something such as...

```
sqlget()
console.log(arrayA)
```

Any advice for how this could be done would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here. You can declare these arrays outside of the function, so you would have something like this:

```
let arrayA = ['something'];
let arrayB = [];

function sqlget() {
  arrayA = [];
  arrayB = [];

  con.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err,result,fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      arrayA.push(result[key].columnA);
      arrayB.push(result[key].columnB);
    });
  });
}

sqlget();
console.log(arrayA)
```

Or you could play around, still return the arrays inside the function and return an object with them:

```
function sqlget() {
  const arrayA = [];
  const arrayB = [];
  
  con.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err,result,fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      arrayA.push(result[key].columnA);
      arrayB.push(result[key].columnB);
    });
  });

  return {
    a: arrayA,
    b: arrayB
  };
}

const arrays = sqlget();

console.log(arrays.a);
console.log(arrays.b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define those two arrays outside of the function. When you define a variable inside of {} block or function you can't access outside of this block its called local scope. Please read [javascript scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript)

```
var arrayA = [];
var arrayB = [];

function sqlget() {
  
  con.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err,result,fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
      arrayA.push(result[key].columnA);
      arrayB.push(result[key].columnB);
    });
  });
}
```